# Openerp-How to remove edit option on image?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have this related image (read only) field and in the form view once I click on edit that particular image field shows edit option in it. Please Help me to remove it

Field:-

```
'emp_img':fields.related('employee_id', 'image_medium', type='char', relation='hr.employee', string='', store=True),
```

in xml:-

```
<field name="emp_img" readonly="1" widget='image' class="oe_left oe_avatar" />
```

in form view-edit it shows like this :

[image]

Comment: What version of Odoo are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the `effective_readonly` parameter to the `image` widget that manages the image.

The following should work:

```
<field name="emp_img" readonly="1" widget='image' class="oe_left oe_avatar" attrs="{'effective_readonly': True}" />
```

or you could use add the attribute below on the form you want from the debug mode:

```
attrs="{ &quot;effective_readonly&quot;:True}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I did that using a new CSS file**. Even though it shows edit option over the image , once you make it read only it won't replace the original file. But less in user friendliness.